# How to use induction to prove that if $α+β=β$, then for every $n<ω,α⋅n\le β$ and hence $\alpha\omega\le \beta$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

Here $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals.

I know that it can be done by induction, but searching in my textbook I cannot find how exactly can I deal with it. I am completely new to ordinal arithmetic, so may I please ask for an explicit proof by induction? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the following properties, and if necessary (i.e. if you don't know them) prove them:

$+$ is associative; $+$ is commutative on finite ordinals; $\cdot$ is distributive over $+$ on the left, i.e. $\alpha\cdot(\beta+\gamma) = \alpha\cdot \beta + \alpha\cdot\gamma$ for all ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$; if $\alpha+\beta = \beta$, then $\alpha \leq \beta$

Comment: I have done with the rest part, may I please ask for a proof that if α+β=β, then α≤β?

Comment: Hint: $\alpha$ is an initial segment of $\alpha+\beta$

Comment: Someone here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246925/prove-that-if-alpha-beta-beta-then-alpha-le-beta?noredirect=1#comment4620570_2246925 also says that, which I cannot fully understand so far. I am wondering how can I prove it formally. So if possible, could you please take sometime to write out a solution in the link? Thanks.

Comment: I answered there, if that's fine with you