# Prove that for any ordinals $\gamma,\beta$, $\gamma\le \gamma+\beta$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I have tried using induction, but have been told that there are quite a lot of things which I have not considered. So now I am confused and asking for a formal proof. I am quite new to transfinite induction. Could someone please show me explicitly how should I deal with that? Thanks!

Comment: Transfinite induction is similar to standard induction but with the addition of the limit case.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this post of yours about induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246293/how-to-use-induction-to-prove-that-if-%ce%b1%ce%b2-%ce%b2-then-for-every-n%cf%89-%ce%b1%e2%8b%85n-le-%ce%b2-and),  In the linked post, you say "I am completely new to ordinal arithmetic, so may I please ask for an explicit proof by induction?"; and here you say: "I am quite new to transfinite induction. Could someone please show me explicitly how should I deal with that?"

Comment: It gets very old, very quickly, before we notice the repetition, and the repeated failure to show your own attempts, repeated claims to be "new to ...... ", and repeated pleas for an explicit proof using the method you're new to, instead of using your text, your lecture notes, references, to at least initiate a given proof.  No one learns how to write proofs by only reading others' proof.  Start stepping up to the plate, get your hands dirty, and then, if need be, ask here, along with the work you've done/tried on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfinite induction on $\beta$.

For $\beta=0$, we trivially have $\gamma \leq \gamma = \gamma+0$.

For $\beta = \alpha+1$, we have $\gamma \leq \gamma + \alpha$ by our induction hypothesis, and then $\gamma \leq (\gamma+\alpha)+1 = \gamma+(\alpha+1) = \gamma+\beta$.

For $\beta$ a non-zero limit ordinal, we have $\gamma \leq \gamma+\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\beta$ by our induction hypothesis. Thus, $\gamma \leq \sup\{\gamma+\alpha\mid \alpha < \beta\}=\gamma+\beta$.

Comment: Thanks! But to prove the whole statement, now I am stuck on inducting on $\gamma$.Could you please help?Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to do transfinite induction on $\gamma$. The above proof works for every $\gamma$ without need to assume that the result holds for earlier ordinals.  The reason to induct on $\beta$ is the fact that the (standard) definition of ordinal addition is a transfinite recursion on the second ordinal.

Comment: Thanks! May I please ask why we can use $γ≤γ+α$ for all $α<β$ as a inductive hypothesis instead of prove it?

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 That in simplest terms is how induction works, you assume it up to some number then prove it for that number or the successor of that number.

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 It is exactly as oliverjones said. The entire point of induction is that we have available to us the hypothesis that the result is true for our earlier ordinals. If this idea is confusing still, I recommend first getting comfortable with induction on $\mathbb{N}$. Overall, the idea is that we can imagine all the ordinals set up as dominoes in order. "Knocking over" a domino is the same as the desired result being true for that ordinal...

Comment: ... You start by showing that the first domino $0$ is knocked over, and then that if dominoes before $\beta$ have fallen, then $\beta$ also falls. Of course, it is usually more convenient to split this into two cases; the successor ordinal case (where there actually is a greatest ordinal less than $\beta$) and the non-zero ordinal case (where $\beta$ is the sup of its earlier ordinals). This is because many definitions are stated in such a way that these two cases are distinguished.